# require.js synchronous loading

Tags: import, module, requirejs, synchronous

I'd like to define a module which computes a new dependancy, fetches it and then returns the result. Like so:

```js
define(['defaults', 'get_config_name'], function(defaults, get_config_name) {
    var name = get_config_name();
    var config;
    require.synchronous([configs / '+name'], function(a) {
        config = defaults.extend(a);
    });
    return config;
});
```

Is there a way to do this or a better way to attack this problem?

Comment: I guess for this to work require.js would have to append a script tag to the body then jump into a while loop to suspend execution while it checks for the script to loading.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- You may try to use [synchronous RequireJS call](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/require) `require('configs/'+get_config_name())`, but it will load a module synchronously only if it is **already loaded**, otherwise it will throw an exception. <strike>Loading module/JavaScript file synchronously is technically impossible.</strike>
  ***UPD:*** *It's possible (see Henrique's answer) but highly unrecommended. It blocks JavaScript execution that causes to freezing of the entire page. So, RequireJS doesn't support it.*
- From your use case it seems that you don't need synchronous RequireJS, you need to **return result asynchronously**.
  [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) pattern allows to define dependencies and load them asynchronously, but module's factory function must return result synchronously. The solution may be in using **loader plugin** (details [here](http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) and [here](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/Loader-Plugins)):

  ```js
  // config_loader.js
  define(['defaults', 'get_config_name'], function(defaults, get_config_name) {
      return {
          load: function (resourceId, require, load) {
              var config_name = 'configs/' + get_config_name();
              require([config_name], function(config) {
                  load(defaults.extend(config));
              })
          }
      }
  });

  // application.js
  define(['config_loader!'], function(config) {
      // code using config
  });
  ```
- If `get_config_name()` contains simple logic and doesn't depend on another modules, the better and simpler is calculating on the fly [paths configuration option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths), or in case your config depends on context - [map configuration option](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map).

  ```js
  function get_config_name() {
      // do something
  }
  require.config({
      paths: {
          'config': 'configs/' + get_config_name()
      }
  });
  require(['application', 'defaults', 'config'], function(application, defaults, config) {
      config = defaults.extend(config);
      application.start(config);
  });
  ```

Answer (score 15):

Loading JavaScript synchronously is NOT technically impossible.

```
function loadJS(file){  
   var js = $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: file, async: false }).responseText; //No need to append  
}

console.log('Test is loading...');
loadJS('test.js');
console.log('Test was loaded:', window.loadedModule); //loadedModule come from test.js
```

Comment: Yes @Henrique, you are right. I discovered this technique after I have published the answer. I updated the answer. Thank you! By the way: I think you were downvoted because you published it not as a comment to the answer but as a separate answer.

Comment: No problem.

I published as an answer because I don't have "reputation" to post comments.

Comment: Just fetching the file and assigning it to a variable will run it? What am I missing?

Comment: synchronous XMLHttpRequest and eval is possible at least on chrome and firefox.
note that if using it locally you'll probably need --allow-file-access-from-file

Comment: Now, 2019, this is still working... you can easily reproduce it.
I haven't found anything on specs, but when you fetch an javascript file with `content-type: application/javascript` it will RUN the js code.

To test:
Open chrome dev tools and register my loadJS function and run `loadJS('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js')`

You will see that underscore `_` will be available now (you should test for its non presence before)