# Dojo require with single argument synchronous?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

My company is moving from classic Dojo syntax to AMD. We have a few situations where we need to dynamically load modules synchronously.

Require in dojo doesn't seem to officially support synchronous loading (at least it's not documented anywhere) but it seems to work if you don't pass in the a function as the second argument (in 1.7.2 at least).

```
require(["path/to/my/Module"]);
```

I've added extra latency in Fiddler and it's definitely loading before moving onto the next line.

Does anyone know if this is safe to rely upon? I don't particularly want to litter the codebase with this if it's just a hangover from the classic style that'll be retired in 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

AMD does not support synchronous loading even when using commonJs style requires.  The require function will only load synchronously if the module has already been loaded.  See:

- AMD API:  https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/require#requirestring
- See also: [require.js synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225245/require-js-synchronous#14201304)

If you have already loaded the module asynchronously then it is possible to use commonJs style requires, eg:

```
var lang = require("dojo/_base/lang");
```

However, if you have not already loaded it, it will throw an *undefinedModule* error (I've testet this in v1.9).  If this works in v1.7 then this has been *fixed* in later editions of Dojo.

It is not possible to temporarily put it into synchronous mode either by passing a new config to Dojo, eg:

```
require({"async":false});
```

The async setting can only be set at load time (see: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/amd.html#loader-amd-configuration). Hence, you select either asynchronous or synchronous at the initial load and then you are stuck there.

I would advise refactoring any code that requires synchronous operation.  This is usually possible and the result will be probably be better and quicker code.

Comment: From looking at the AMD API I think it might be a mistake on Dojo's part. The syntax I'm using is not 

    require(string) 
or 
    require(array, function)
it's
    require(array)

The module definitely hasn't been loaded yet because I'm calling it in a unit test where I specifically don't require it beforehand. It's loading synchronously because I used fiddler to increase the latency of the call for 2000ms and it waited for it to load.

Comment: I've tried to replicate this but have not been able to do so (using both v1.9 & v.1.7.2).  I've used the array format (with no callback) as you have done but it still loads asynchronously.  Perhaps you are using different settings?  I have {cacheBust:true, async:true} - have tried with local Dojo and using Google CDN.  Even if it is working synchronously, I would assume that this will at a future and random time switch to asynchronous - ie. it is probably using a unknown flaw in the loader.  I'm not an expert on the Dojo loader so I cannot say for sure if this is correct behavior or not.