# About requirejs asynchronous

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I hava two js file ：

```
//loading.js
define(function () {
    function Loading(config) {

    }
    Loading.prototype.show = function () {

    };
    Loading.prototype.hide = function () {

    };
    return function (config) {
        return new Loading(config);
    };
});

//util.js
define(function () {
    var util = {};
    util.loading = function (config) {
        var result = null;
        //I want this code synchronous
        require(["loading"],function (Loading) {
            result = Loading(config);
        });
        //there will be result null because of asynchronous
        return result;
    };
    return util;
});
```

At present,I solve this problem like this:

```
define(["loading"],function (Loading) {
    var util = {};
    util.loading = function (config) {
        return  Loading(config);
    };
    return util;
});
```

But I don't like this way.
I want to know requirejs whether to support load js file synchronous.
If not,have a way to solve this problem?
I have seem this question [require.js synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225245/require-js-synchronous),feel the answer not solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [require.js synchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225245/require-js-synchronous)

Comment: @craigts I have seen this answer, don't feel the same.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to your second code snippet is this:

```
define(function (require) {
    var Loading = require("loading");
    var util = {};
    util.loading = function (config) {
        return  Loading(config);
    };
    return util;
});
```

Note however, that this is still loading the module named "loading" asynchronously even if it *looks* synchronous.

The thing is that RequireJS in the browser is *always* loading modules asynchronously. This is true even if it *looks* synchronous. RequireJS is meant to load modules that conform to the Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) spec, which is an inherently asynchronous method to load modules. If you want something that looks synchronous and is synchronous you should switch to a module spec that works synchronously.

Comment: Thank you for your help.