# requireJS element is not a function

Tags: javascript, requirejs

simple example RequireJs
I get Error :
Uncaught TypeError: hi is not a function

say.js

```
define(function () { 
    var say={};
    say.hi=function hi(){
    console.log('hi');
    }
    return say;
});
```

index.html

```
<script src="/js/require.js"  data-main="/js/config.js"  ></script>
<script>
    var hi; 
    require(['say'], function(say){
        hi=function() { say.hi();}
    }); 
    hi();
</script>
```

config.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/js',
    paths: {jquery: 'jquery'},   
});
```

Comment: Most likely because the callback function for `require()` is called asynchronously

Comment: See: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)

Comment: @NickParsons , How to coorect it ,  I think the same code works with me fine Before , but now get error ,  something is missing

Comment: I'm not familiar with requirejs, so not sure if there is a synchronous version (and if there is, you'd most likely want to try and avoid that if you can). But typically you'd need to put the code that relies on `say`/`hi` into the requirejs callback. Or, be sure that when you try and call `hi` that you're calling it _after_ the `require()` callback has been executed (which is difficult to do/be sure of). Also see [require.js synchronous loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14201304)

Comment: @NickParsons , it's works with setTimeout(function() {hi();}, 1000);

Comment: Only if the module is able to be loaded in 1 second, which mostly should be the case, but not guaranteed. If you're going to do that, put the call to `hi` inside your `require()` callback instead of trying to guess when it's available with `setTimeout()`.